# Issues with pgrouting createtopology() and rows_where condition

Tags: postgresql, postgis, pgrouting

I am attempting to run createtopology on a database where tags match certain conditions with a jsonb datacolumn but the command fails on the rows_where condition and I don't know why.

The Database is setup under the schema 'berlin' and has tables 'nodes', 'ways', and 'routes' and I'm trying to run it on the ways table obviously.

berlin.ways has the following columns and datatypes:

```
way_id - int
tags - jsonb
geom - linestring
dist - real
source - int
target - int
```

and I am trying to run:

```
SELECT pgr_createTopology('berlin.ways', 10, id:='way_id', the_geom:='geom', rows_where:=(tags @> '{"subway":"yes"}'::jsonb));
```

This returns the error: column "tags" does not exist. I've switched it to berlin.ways.tags and get the error: missing FROM-clause entry for table "ways"

I am very new to postgres/sql in general

Comment: Hmmm, it should work this way after reading the docs. What happens if you do something simple like using  rows_where:='way_id < X' ? Does it work? Can you also instead turn the rows_where into a select query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pgr_createTopology` can receive the option `rows_where`, which is the condition that **will** be applied on the targeted table. The type of `rows_where` is therefore a text.

By using an expression instead of a text, you are building the `rows_where` clause, which can't work because there is not even a `from` clause (it would have worked - but it is not the intent - with something like `select pgr_createTopology(... , rows_where=my_where_clause_column) from my_where_clause_table where id=123`)

So the solution is to quote the `rows_where` clause, possibly with dollar-quotes to avoid having to escape the single quotes:

```sql
SELECT pgr_createTopology('berlin.ways', 10, id:='way_id', the_geom:='geom', rows_where:=$$(tags @> '{"subway":"yes"}'::jsonb)$$);
```